# do not display the number in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can do anything I can not print numbers inside html tags by bs4

```
span class="open" dir="ltr">31.28</span
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: you use .text to retrieve text for items in the list returned by select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to extract the numeric value contained in that class, you could do the following :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<span> class="open" dir="ltr">31.28</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
data = soup.findAll("span")
numbers = [d.get_text() for d in data]

print(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
But only the letters are printed
Numbers are not printed

Comment: Again just the letters
:(